# sortable columns for multiple custom post types not working

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, hooks, admin, wp-list-table

I have two custom post types named `professor` and `campus`.
To each of these CPT's I have added two custom admin columns named `image` and `last_modified`, which currently display correctly on both CPT's admin tables.

I have also filtered each CPT by post_type, however the `manage_edit-post_sortable_columns` is not displaying the titles as sortable in the admin tables.

I thought if I used `manage_edit-post_sortable_columns` I could target the ones I have conditionally checked for?

Am I missing something?

Here is the code:

```
// add featured image and last modified columns to cpt admin tables (works correctly)
function cpt_columns($columns) {
    global $current_screen;
    if (in_array($current_screen->post_type, array('professor', 'campus'))) {
        $columns['last_modified'] = 'Last Modified';
        $columns['post_thumbs'] = 'Image';
    }
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'cpt_columns');


// custom columns as sortable (not working)
function cpt_columns_sortable($columns) {
    global $current_screen;
    if (in_array($current_screen->post_type, array('professor', 'campus'))) {
        $columns['last_modified'] = 'Last Modified';
        $columns['post_thumbs'] = 'Image';
    }
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-post_sortable_columns', 'cpt_columns_sortable');


// output custom column content
function cpt_columns_content($column_id, $post_id) {
    if ($column_id == 'last_modified') {
        echo get_post_field('post_modified', $post_id);
    } else if ('post_thumbs') {
        echo the_post_thumbnail('xsm_thumbnail');
    }
}
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'cpt_columns_content', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought if I used `manage_edit-post_sortable_columns` I could target
> the ones I have conditionally checked for?

That hook runs only on the "Posts" page (at `wp-admin/edit.php`) for managing posts in the default/core `post` post type. I.e. When the `post_type` parameter in the (current page) URL is not set or empty, or that it's set to `post`.

For other post types like `page` and your `campus` CPT, use `edit-<post type>` in place of `edit-post`.

So replace the `add_filter('manage_edit-post_sortable_columns', 'cpt_columns_sortable');` with:

```php
add_filter('manage_edit-campus_sortable_columns',    'cpt_columns_sortable');
add_filter('manage_edit-professor_sortable_columns', 'cpt_columns_sortable');
```

Apart from that, you also need to correct the `$columns` format you used, where the correct one is `$columns['<column name/slug>'] = '<orderby value passed to WP_Query>'`, and **not** `$columns['<column name/slug>'] = '<column title>'`.

Therefore in your `cpt_columns_sortable()` function:

```php
// Use this:
$columns['last_modified'] = 'modified';    // 'modified' is a synonym for post_modified
$columns['post_thumbs']   = 'post_thumbs'; // post_thumbs is a custom orderby value

/* Not this:
$columns['last_modified'] = 'Last Modified';
$columns['post_thumbs'] = 'Image';
*/
```

And that should work, for making the posts sortable by the modification date, because `modified` is a standard orderby value for `WP_Query`.

But as for sorting the posts by the post thumbnails (?), you'll need to handle that on your own, e.g. using the `pre_get_posts` hook.

And note that [`the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/) echo the output, so don't do "echo the_post_thumbnail".

Comment: Sally CJ, thanks for clearing that up for me. I didn't realize to add separate filters for each cpt and removing the echo with `the_post_thumbnail()`, silly me. Is not the `post_thumbs` column sort the posts by the post thumbnails anyway in the table by the manage sortable filter hook?

Comment: `post_thumbs` (or any other custom orderby values) does make the posts sortable by that value, i.e. you'd get `orderby=post_thumbs` in the URL, but to actually sort the posts by that, you need to write your own code.

Comment: Okay, thanks Sally for your help.